# WPF 4.0 finger panning in listbox

Tags: wpf, windows-7, scroll, multi-touch

WPF 4.0 is "supposed" to have multi-touch scrolling and panning baked into the scrollviewer. However, I cannot seem to get this to work with ListBoxes. I've tried all different combinations of PanningMode, IsManipulationEnabled, etc. How do I make a listbox scroll with windows 7 touch?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" FontSize="18"
             IsManipulationEnabled="False"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalFirst"
             Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False"
             Stylus.IsTouchFeedbackEnabled="True"
        >
        </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the Bamboo drivers on my system that cancelled out the wpf touch events from firing.

See the link below if you have a Bamboo ...

[Bamboo drivers disable WPF4 touch events](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551392/bamboo-drivers-disable-wpf4-multitouch-events)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, normally, you don't need to explicitly enable *anything* in order to make a WPF application respond to basic touch events and manipulations.

To start troubleshooting, and sorry for the perhaps stupid question: Are you sure touch input is enabled on your system, in the first place? That is, can you use other applications (Explorer, Paint etc.) with touch / multi-touch?

Comment: Yes, but only wpf4 was hosed because of the bamboo drivers.

Answer (score 2):

it should work with 2 fingers right out of the box.  if you want to have touch panning work with 1 finger, you'll need to use the SurfaceListBox control from the "Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch"